# How to change key value in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So. I was trying something like that:

```
var mykey = 'answer01count'; 

x[mykey] = 2;
```

For example needs, but that only change the value for existing session but not changing my json file... There is a way to changing key value? I Mean i need to create counter in questions, so every time user will answer a question value will increase, by 1. And after some one will answer on same question he will see that someone before him answer this question before.

My Json file:

```
{   "title":"something",
        "id": "1",
        "date":"08J", 
        "question":"What is a Capital of United Kingdom:",
        "answer01": "Warsaw",
        "answer02": "London",
        "answer03": "New York",
        "answer04": "Budapest",
        "answer05": "Paris",
        "correct": "London",
        "answer01count": "0",
        "answer02count": "0",
        "answer03count": "0",
        "answer04count": "0",
        "answer05count": "0"
         },
```

So as you see i need to count each question. There is a way to do it in JSON? or i need to use PHP??!!

I forgett to add that html file and json are separate. and i using script for get a json call:

```
$(function() {
  val = 0;

  $.getJSON("question.json", function(response) {
      json = response;
      populate(json.data[val]);
  });});
```

Comment: The client of course does not have access to change the contents of the file on the server. Assuming the json file lives on your server, you will need some server-side processing (php will do fine) to make any updates to it.

Comment: If you want to save the JSON file on the server, that has to be done at server-side.

Comment: can you give ma a sample example from php? or schould i add "PHP" inside question TAG?

Comment: You can use any server side language you want. It doesn't have to be PHP.

Comment: thank, i think i going to use ajax.

Comment: Ajax is only a way of making a request to the server (and you are already using it by using `$.getJSON`). You still need to implement the server side to accept some data and write it to the file.